# Are there sub-schools of Dvaita Vedanta?

Tags: dvaita

Are there sub-schools of Dvaita Vedanta, other than Madhava school?

Madhava adopts Eternal Damnation for the third category of jivas. Are there sub-schools of Dvaita which adopt Universal Salvation of all classes of Jivas?

Comment: It only Madhva Tattva vada says this from BG.16.19-16.20 slokha Sriman Madhvaacharya never quoted out of his own its all from vedas, upanishad and b.g.  All other school are Advaita or its derivative.. its like derivative trading instead of actual stock but you are trading in the same stock altogether. See below answer achitya bheda aabheda philosopy..

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no subschools per se, but many 'subsampradayas' have emerged based on regional differences. There is taulava, deshasta, gauda sarasvatha, etc. There is no doubt on any of the philosophical views, but some differences in food, rituals, and preferences in worship. All follow madhwacharya, jayathirtha, vyasathirtha, vadiraja, etc, as well as their own gurus from their regional mathas.

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)